# extracting ROS laserscan messages from a given pose and a pointcloud

Tags: ros

I have a ply file which is the pointcloud of an environment. I also have a csv file which has the pose of the quadcopter at every instants. Given these both as input, I want to extract planar laserscan data as a ROS laserscan message. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in ROS named **pointcloud_to_laserscan** ( [Documentation of pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan)) that converts the 3D pointcloud data to 2D laserscan message.